# How to return object that requires an API key to client from server?

Tags: javascript, security, browser, key, server

Let me first say, I really am inexperienced in the area of security but I do see a big flaw in some of my code right now. Anyways, so one of the API's I am using client side requires the use of an API key. Upon signing up/making an account with them, they give you an API key. Being a client side library, this api key is used to create your object like so:

```
  if(!obj){
    obj = new APIOBJ('asdjf9sdfs009a8sd0fasd'); // Key is given to you
  }
```

However, this is clearly accessible to the client. I figured this is bad, since anyone could look in the console and dig it up if they wanted. And if I decided to request the server for the key, that wouldn't work either since that too would just be seen. So I figured, maybe if the server can send back the object for me to use, then I can avoid this issue. So my questions are:

1. Is this the right approach?
2. How does one do this? (Since to me this is like, if jQuery required the use of an API key to use)

Thanks!

**Edit**:

The API in question is Icecomm.io, a wrapper for WebRTC.

Comment: Did this key come along with a private key for you to use on your server side?

Comment: No, just a string that is to be handed to the constructor.

Comment: That must not be for sensitive data then?

Comment: Yea not at all, just i figure since its specific to me, I should not be giving it out right?

Comment: I guess, unless It is some sort of general key (non user specific) and they want t control their API versions or something? What is the API?

Comment: I'll edit the main question with this info.